# Is it possible to mod both PC versions of GTA 4?

Tags: pc, version-differences, grand-theft-auto-iv

I'm considering purchasing GTA 4, and I'm leaning towards the two-disc physical version, but I'm worried it might not be possible to mod the physical version of the game.

Does purchasing the game digitally change anything? Can both the physical and digital versions be modded? Is there a difference?

Comment: @Dustinballistic Even with the disc version you still have to install the game. The result is largely the same - you end up with the game files on your HDD and the DVD is used mainly for verification. You would be better off troubleshooting the Steam version.

Comment: But theres two discs.  Isn't the second disc for game software installation

Comment: @Dustinballistic It's been quite a while since I installed my PC version of GTA4, but I believe both discs are involved in the installation. Really, if you had a technical issue with the Steam version it is likely to be present in the boxed version. If you want to make a new question about troubleshooting the Steam edition I'm sure someone here could help you.

Comment: Thanks :).  The social club loads up great , but thats the only thing that loads.  The loading circle on the right side of the mouse shows up for a few seconds and  disappear's and nothing loads.

Comment: I've edited this question to focus on the differences between versions and whether they can be modded (which was the underlying question that OP wanted to answer), and reopened it as such because such questions are on-topic for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two versions, at least not when it comes to modding or actually getting it to run.

The Steam version of the game does not use Steam Workshop so all mods are handled through other sites. Steam will not make it any easier to mod.

Regarding getting the game to run, the error is almost certainly not caused by the Steam version. If it was, it'd probably affect other Steam games. Buying the retail version will probably not magically fix it.